# Package installer missing on TexMaker + BasicTex on MacBook

Tags: packages, texmaker, mac, compilation-error

This might have been answered elsewhere, but I could not benefit from the answers I found.
I have installed the TexMaker editor and the [BasicTex](https://www.tug.org/mactex/BasicTeX.pdf) distribution on a MacBook running macOS Big Sur 11.2.3. I have avoided MacTex to save space. Of course, more packages are required on the fly, hence the following error message:

> LaTeX Error: File `makecell.sty' not found.Type X to quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop. \usepackage

On my previous MacBook I had TexMaker with MacTex and a dialog used to pop up whenever a new package was required. Here there is no such a dialog, and I am left with the above error message.
Any hint on how to install additional packages? Did I miss anything? This is my Library folder structure, where the TeX Distribution lies.

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Are you sure? I never heard MacTeX poping up to install a package. You need to use the `tlmgr` command line too to install packages.

Comment: What's  your distribution? TeXLive or MiKTeX?

Comment: @Bernard BasicTex is based on TeXLive. I have added the link in my question.

Comment: @daleif thank you. Is there a specific directory where I should use the tlmgr command line? I have edited the question to show the folder structure where the distribution lies.

Comment: If your basic tex is in the PATH then it does not matter.